# Measure Epoch time in Nanoseconds - Android

Tags: android, datetime, epoch, nanotime

How to find the time since Epoch in nanoseconds in Android?

Below APIS are available but they just give the time since boot

1. `SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()` - Time since boot but includes deep sleep time
2. `System.getnano()` -> This is up time since boot without the deep sleep time.

For Epoch time, there seems to be only 1 API available.

- `System.currentTimeMillis()` -> shows time since Epoch in milliseconds.

Is there a similar API/a new approach to get the time since epoch in nano seconds.

PS : Time since Epoch means, the time elapsed since January 1, 1970 UTC.

Comment: Java does not offer the `clock_gettime` function, so your choice to have more accurate timing is through JNI, also there would be an overhead calling JNI so it would not 100% accurate

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Thank you. I see that System.currentTimeMillis() is also a native call. So I guess, it will be kind of ok for me to use JNI, but i was looking for available APIS in android that can give me the nanoseconds.. I guess there are none available as of now.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I am trying to look at the native implementation of currentTimeMillis() but unable to find the souce. If you know where is it, please share with me.. It will help me.

Comment: You can either check it in you local jdk folder the name of the file is `os_solaris.cpp` or you can just go here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u60/hotspot/file/ba66650acf63/src/os/solaris/vm/os_solaris.cpp#l1805

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the millis to nanos with the TimeUnit class. Try

```
long nanos = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: This would just convert it. It would not be accurate. I would like to measure the actual time in naoseconds

Answer (score 0):

Device doesn't have so accurate clock to count nanoseconds when device is off. CPU does, but it counts only from start.

Comment: I dont think so. You can get the nano seconds using clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts) from native code. I verified it from native code. It works fine. I am looking to get a similar value from android application without using JNI/native code..